# jQuery contextMenu load items via Ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, contextmenu

I am using the below context menu plugin for jQuery 1.8.11.js and using the "build"  callback to dynamically create the menu on every click.

http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html

I'd like to be able to load the menu options dynamically when an item is clicked (calling a controller method that determines the available options depending on the ID of the item)

My problem is that this context menu library doesn't seem to support ajax calls, and if I try to make an ajax call in the 'build' callback, it obviously will not wait until the ajax call is complete.

Here is a trimmed-down snippet of what I am trying to do:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '" + contextMenuSelector + @"',
    build: function ($trigger, e) {
    menuOptionsArray = [];
        //Ajax START
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: <myurl>,
             //async: false, //**IF I UN-COMMENT THIS, IT WORKS**
             context: $(this),
             success: function (data) {
                   //BUILD THE OPTIONS ARRAY
                   menuOptionsArray...
                }
            });
         //Ajax END

         //This returns before the ajax call finishes               
         return {
            items: menuOptionsArray
        };
    }
```

In the above, setting async = false works, but since that is deprecated, I don't want to use that.

Is there any other way to load the items asynchronously, or would this require a modification of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I switched to jQuery UI menu widget and used the focus event and refresh function.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3r5FX/

Here I wrote some about it:
http://imnotsmartjustlucky.blogspot.se/2013/06/jquery-context-menu-asynchronousajax.html

Extract of the code:
HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" style="width:300px">
 <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Aberdeen</a></li>
 <li>
  <a href="#">Delphi</a>
  <ul>
                 <li><a href="#"><img src="http://cdn-3.nikon-cdn.com/static/images/icons/icon_loading.gif"/></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Saarland</a></li>
 <li class="ui-state-disabled"><a href="#">Amesville</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu").menu({
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.item.children("ul").children("li").children("a").children("img").length > 0){
                $.get("http://fiddle.jshell.net", function(data){
                    ui.item.children("ul").html("<li><a href='#'>Viktor</a></li><li><a href='#'>Sweden</a></li><li><a href='#'>Luleå</a></li>")
                    $("#menu").menu("refresh")
                })
            }
        }
    });

});
```